# flutter_map zoom not updating

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap, fluttermap

I am using the flutter_map plugin with OpenStreetMap as a provider. I have two buttons for changing zoom level, that increase/decrease the currentZoom variable (double).

In the build override of my widget, I am rebuilding the map as follow:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterMap currentmap = FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
        center: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        onTap: (pos) {
          print(pos);
        },
        zoom: currentZoom,
        // debug: true,
      ),
      layers: [
        TileLayerOptions(
          overrideTilesWhenUrlChanges: false,
          urlTemplate:
              "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?source=${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}",
          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          additionalOptions: {},
        ),
```

, then currentMap is used as the child of a canvas, which does work perfectly.

Please notice I have added a ?source=at the end of the URL to force cache update (but removing this argument does not solve the problem neither).

However, when I change the currentZoom level in the buttons onPressed callbacks and then call SetState, the page is rebuilt but the map zoom level does not change at all.

Here is the callback:

```
IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline_rounded),
                            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                              currentZoom =
                                  currentZoom < 1 ? 0 : currentZoom - 1;
                              print(currentZoom);
                            }),
                          ),
```

In the callbacks, I have console logs that are showing the currentZoom variable is correctly updated.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `MapController` and call `mapController.move(currentCenter, currentZoom)` 
code snippet

```
double currentZoom = 13.0;
MapController mapController = MapController();
LatLng currentCenter = LatLng(51.5, -0.09);

void _zoom() {
    currentZoom = currentZoom - 1;
    mapController.move(currentCenter, currentZoom);
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double currentZoom = 13.0;
  MapController mapController = MapController();
  LatLng currentCenter = LatLng(51.5, -0.09);

  void _zoom() {
    currentZoom = currentZoom - 1;
    mapController.move(currentCenter, currentZoom);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FlutterMap(
          mapController: mapController,
          options: MapOptions(
            center: currentCenter,
            onTap: (pos) {
              print(pos);
            },
            zoom: currentZoom,
            // debug: true,
          ),
          layers: [
            TileLayerOptions(
              overrideTilesWhenUrlChanges: false,
              urlTemplate:
                  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?source=${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}",
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
              additionalOptions: {},
            )
          ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _zoom,
        tooltip: 'Zoom',
        child: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was indeed missing the MapController api. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[To Sustain user in one point and keep zooming in/out there]

Now you can use onMapEvent(mapEvent){} function under MapOptions, then

1. Check if current event is MapEventMove and then set new center as initial center

   `if (mapEvent is MapEventMove) { initialCenter = mapEvent.camera.center; }`

2, and call

```
mapController.move(initialCenter, currentZoom);
```

or you can use `currentZoom += 0.2` to zoom in and
`currentZoom -=0.2` to zoom out.